# Mouseleave event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation menu. When the user leaves the li I want the menu to wait for a short value of time before closing. Previously I made the code apply which worked fine until I wanted to give different delays. **The issue is the event does not trigger.**

I tried making a version of the item on jsfiddle which works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/cv6t7yqw/

My code:

```js
$("#nextLeftNav li, #prevLeftNav li").on("mouseleave", function (event) {
            var element = $(event.currentTarget);
            element.removeClass("hover");
            var delayMs = 600;
            if($(this).is("#nextLeftNav li"))
            {
             delayMs = 3000;
            }
            timeOutMethod = setTimeout(timeoutNavbar, delayMs, element);     
});

function timeoutNavbar(){
    console.log("timeOutNavBar")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="prevLeftNav">
  <li>
    <span class="chevron top">
    </span>
  </li>
</div>
```

When I inspect prevLeftNav's only li I see the dimensions of around 200x20 and can physically see the li.

Comment: If the content is dynamically added, that function will not bind to the element. Try using `.on`'s 2nd parameter.

Comment: try mouseout https://jsfiddle.net/cv6t7yqw/1/

Comment: A couple of possible reasons: 1) The element is added dynamically, so the handler won't be bound to it. 2) Your handler is being unbound with a call to `.off()` after your call to `.on()`.

Comment: @Lidaranis Mouseout didn't work.

Comment: @SamedDüzçay the content is dynamically added. Is this a problem? I'll have a look at on's second parameter just now.

Comment: @user3245390 are you sure? fiddle seems to be working  https://jsfiddle.net/cv6t7yqw/2/

Comment: @user3245390 if the content is added dynamically, you have to bind the event handler once the element  is added. So for any *DOM* change that involve the elements you're working on.

Comment: @MarioSantini To clarify I need to use .bind on #prevLeftNav and add a mouseleave event? If so thank you.

Comment: @Lidaranis You have misread the question but thank you for trying anyways.

Comment: @user3245390 your question has issue first of all. Mention that you have added elements dynamically. Fiddle is does not depict that.

Comment: @ScanQR I'm sorry but you don't have to take it out on me that you misread the question. I saw your comment before you deleted it. If it's not apparent I'm not exactly experienced in jQuery so I didn't know that that was a problem. The JSFiddle was only there to show the logic itself is correct and that I am sure that the problem is the event is not firing.